# Algorithm to get the combinations in lesser number of iteration

Tags: java, python, algorithm, breadth-first-search, a-star

I am wring a logic to get the combinations for an iteration based on the below criteria. I have the working code which take care of it. I wonder If I can reduce the number of iterations in it

A,B,C,D,E,F,G are set of nodes in the below example

[image]

**Criteria:**

**To get the list of elements.**
  1. There should not be any repeating nodes in it. eg.. AB can be there BA should not be there 
  2. Diagonal element should not be there  eg.. AA,BB...

Once after accomplishing the logic we get all the coloured ones (not the black/grey coloured ones)
AB,AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, BC, BD, BE, BF, BG, CD,CE, CF, CG, DE, DF, DG, EF, EG, FG

**To get the group of elements in an iteration**
The elements has to be grouped for an iteration based on the below rules

**1st iteration**
1. Pick an element. Let us say AB
2. The element which will be picked should not have A or B . Hence CD can be picked.
3. Once completing this above 2 steps we will get the elements for 1st iteration

At the end of 1st iteration we would have collected  AB,CD, EF

4. Now repeat the Step1 to 3 to get the elements for 2nd iteration

At the end of 2nd iteration we would have collected  AC,BD, EG

Like this the number of iteration will be done to get the elements for each iteration.

**Question:**
As the elements I expect will be around 100, I wonder is there is any best method to reduce the number of iterations. I hope there will not be a way. But as we have algorithm  experts here I need a advice here.

Comment: If you need to generate 7 sets, you cannot have less than 7 iterations. You're actually going to have `n(n -1)/2` iterations, if you have a square with side `n`. For a 100 x 100 you're going to have 4950 iterations, and for a 7 x 7 you're going to have 21

Comment: How about 7 X 9

Comment: 4950 will be number of elements.. how about the number of iterations

Comment: How do you plan on generating an element without iterating on it?

Comment: My for loop will be iterated untill all the elements are done.

Comment: Yes, which means that you'll have one iteration for every element, which is what I just said.

Comment: So if I use 12 nodes will I get 12 iterations?  Based on my logic I am getting 16 iterations

Comment: No, I meant for every *result* element. If you can get the result of a 12 x 12 product (which is 66 elements) with only 16 iterations, please share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [round-robin tournament algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament)

Place items in two row (with empty place if number is odd), here I made pairs for your AB/CD/EF example

```
A  C  E  G     
B  D  F  .
pairs  AB CD EF
```

Fix the first element (A) and at every step rotate other items in a cyclic way (ordering differs from yours). Finally you'll get `N-1` sets of `N/2` pairs

```
A  B  C  E
D  F  G  .  
pairs  AD BF CG
and so on
A  D  B  C 
F  G  E  .  

A  F  D  B 
G  E  C  .  

A  G  F  D  
E  C  B  .  

A  E  G  F  
C  B  D  .
```

Comment: So in my case, How may iteration u expect ? is it going to be less than 7

Comment: Ah, I missed 7-th item. No, exactly 7 iterations. In any case you must generate N*(N-1)/2 possible pairs, So using  N iterations, every gives N/2 pairs, is optimal

Comment: How about asymmetric case.. say 7 X 9.  Any formulae for possible pairs and number of iterations ?

Comment: How asymmetric case is possible?

Comment: A,B,C,D,E,FG.   VS.   A,B,C,D,E,FG,H,I.

Comment: Or it may be A,B,C,D,E,FG.  Vs I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q

Comment: The last case corresponds to "Scheveningen_system" and it is quite easy - rotate the second group. The second one is more complex.

Comment: Going back to my question, I assume if I use 7 nodes. Then 7 iterations will be needed.  Same way if I use 12 nodes will I get 12 iterations?    Actually based on my logic code.. I am getting 16....  Is there is any formulae for getting number of iterations to cross verify my number of iterations is correct or not ?

Comment: Round-robin algo shows us that there are **N-1** rounds (I erroneously wrote N)  to provide all possible non-intersecting pairings for `N` participants. So for 12 nodes - 11 iterations.